# Redirect a wordpress widget after successful form submission

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have made a contact form widget for wordpress using their widget api it works but I want to send the user to a thank you page. The problem is the headers have already been sent by the time the widget is processed. From what I understand I have to hook onto one of wordpresses actions to load the widget at the right time but I'm not sure how to do that.

I've seen this post [Wordpress Widget Redirect Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711378/wordpress-widget-redirect-page) and tried several things but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to redirect the users page.

Comment: I want it to work for people not using javascript as well though.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I didn't actually post how - I've never done it :)
Could you have the form post to a different page that loads your code first?